# PHP regex doesn't match?

Tags: php

I have the following RegEx

`@version:\'(?:CKEditor )?([\d\.]+)(?:.+revision:\'([\d]+))?@`

And it should match

`version:"4.0 Beta"`

and return 4.0 Beta

But it doesn't seem to be working? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex matches a single quote, not a double quote.  Try the following instead.

```
@version:\"(?:CKEditor )?([\d\.]+)(?:.+revision:\"([\d]+))?@
```